# How to add strong types to this switch alternative function?

Tags: typescript, types

```js
const switchcase = (value, cases, defaultCase) => {
  const valueString = String(value);
  const result = Object.keys(cases).includes(valueString)
    ? cases[valueString]
    : defaultCase;
  return typeof result === 'function' ? result() : result;
};
```

I'd like to understand how to add types to the JavaScript function above while avoiding the use of `any` unless necessary. I realize that the `value` parameter is probably `any`, but I'm not sure for `cases`, `defaultCase`, and the return type of the function.

Thanks, in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return type of the function depends on what you expect to return.

Here's one take on it, though. You'd need to amend `ExpectedReturnType` to reflect what you want out of the function, and your cases would need to either be that type, or would need to be functions that have an arity of 0 and return your expected return type.

```js
interface ExpectedReturnType {}

// Each case is either a function that produces the return type
// or the type itself
type CaseType = ExpectedReturnType | (() => ExpectedReturnType);

const switchcase = (
  value: any,
  cases: { [key: string]: CaseType },
  defaultCase: CaseType
): ExpectedReturnType => {
  const valueString = String(value);
  const result = valueString in cases ? cases[valueString] : defaultCase;
  return typeof result === "function" ? result() : result;
};
```

You could also make use of a generic:

```
function switchcase<T, U = T | (() => T)>(
  value: any,
  cases: { [key: string]: U },
  defaultCase: U
): T {
  const valueString = String(value);
  const result = valueString in cases ? cases[valueString] : defaultCase;
  return typeof result === "function" ? (result as Function)() : result;
}

// And you'd use it like so:
const cases = { foo: "bar", whee: () => "yay" };
switchcase("foo", cases, "bar");

// Or so:
switchcase<string>("foo", cases, "bar");
```

Typescript would hopefully infer `T` from your parameters passed, but you could always call it as `switchcase<SomeType>(...)` if you need to key it specifically.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I’m trying to add types to use it generically as a module. With that in mind, I’m not sure that an empty interface is the right return type. Can you address that information in your answer?

Comment: The empty interface is not the correct answer, of course. Hence my comment about why "it depends on what you expect the function to return". You can parameterize it with a generic, though; I'll adapt my answer to that.

Comment: Yeah, the updated version is more like what I imagined. I’m still learning about inference in regard to generics, so I’m going to have to spend some time examining this.

Comment: The idea with generics is that the type of `T` is either inferred through usage, or specified with the angle bracket syntax. We say that `cases` and `defaultCase` both take a parameter of some type `U`, which is either either some parameter of type `T`, or some zero-arity function which produces a value of type  `T`. The function itself returns a value of type of `T`. What `T` actually is depends on how you use switchcase.

Comment: Thanks for adding more info about generic inferences—that helped. I still don't understand a couple of things: (1) Why can't TypeScript infer that `result` is a callable function on the `return` line... why is the type assertion necessary after the `function` type has been established via the runtime conditional? (2) If the types for cases were defined separately, would it look like this? `type Case<T> = T | (() => T);` `type Cases<T> = {[key: string]: Case<T>};` `type Switchcase = <T>(value: any, cases: Cases<T>, defaultCase: Case<T>) => T;`

Comment: (1) We're telling Typescript that our return type may be either a function or another type. Which it actually is isn't available until runtime, where type information isn't available. `typeof(x) === "function"` isn't sufficient for compile-time narrowing to a `Function` type. You'd need to use a type guard instead. (2) Yes, that looks about right.